# Printing a grid in C

Tags: c, arrays, grid

I'm trying to print a grid in C in order to put an object moving on it later. This is how the output should be:

```
- - -
- - -
- - -
```

But i keep getting the error `excess elements in char array initializer`, i don't know why, any advice?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define X 3
#define Y 3

// Print the array
void printArray(char row[][Y], size_t one, size_t two)
{
   // output column heads
   printf("%s", "       [0]  [1]  [2]");
   // output the row in tabular format
   for (size_t i = 0; i < one; ++i) {
      // output label for row
      printf("\nrow[%lu] ", i);
      // output grades for one student
      for (size_t j = 0; j < two; ++j) {
         printf("%-5d", row[i][j]);
      } 
   } 
} 

int main(void)
{
   // initialize student grades for three students (rows)
   char row[X][Y] =  
      { { "-", "-", "-"},
        { "-", "-", "-"},
        { "-", "-", "-"} };
   // output the row
   puts("The array is:");
   printArray(row, X, Y);

}
```

Comment: try changing the double cotation " to a single ' in the array, cuz this is how characters are in c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First, you should change `"-"` to `'-'`. Because the `"-"` is a string and contains `'\0'` implicitly. So the `"-"` length is 9 because a byte length is 8.
2. You should change the print:

   `printf("%-5d", row[i][j]);`

   to :

   `printf("%-5c", row[i][j]);`

Comment: @alpha: strings do not contain `'\n'` implicitly; they contain `'\0'` by definition. The string `"foobar"` occupies 7 bytes though its length is 6.